# y and x not the same length, scatterplot R

Tags: r, plot, reshape2, melt

take the following as a simple example:

```
A <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
B <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)
C <- c(6,3,2,4,1,2,6,8,4,3)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C)
data
```

I want to create a scatterplot that looks like so:
without the blue and red boarders, they are there as an explanitary guide

[image]

So I want to plot:
Each time B=1, I want to use its C value for the horizontal scale and plot the C value where B=0 along the vertical scale.

So for example; where `X=6`, we have points at `x=3 and 2`

where `X=4`, we have points at `x=1`

where `X=2`, we have a point at `x=6`

where `X=8`, we have a points at `x=4 and 3`

Must i manipuulate/melt/reshape my data somehow?

Comment: Not sure if i understand. Shouldn't `X=4` have points at `X=1` but not at 2?

Comment: true, that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `na.locf` from the `zoo` package there is no need for reshaping.

```
library(zoo)

#extract the part of C that we need for mapping x
data$D = ifelse(data$B==1,data$C,NA)

#fill in the blanks
data$D = na.locf(data$D)

#Extract from C what we need for y
data$E = ifelse(data$B==1,NA,data$C)

#Done!
plot(data$D,data$E)
```